# Type '{ children: never[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Typescript + React Error when trying to render Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, navbar

I'm currently trying to render a simple navbar from Material UI into my homepage. Currently, I've made a Navbar.tsx file and I'm trying to call the Navbar const I made. I'm running into that type error though.

Here is my Navbar.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';

import '../styles/components/HomePageComponent.scss';
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {AppBar, Toolbar, Typography} from '@material-ui/core/';


const Navbar = () =>  {
  
  return(
    <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Typography>This is our header! </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
    
};

export default Navbar;
```

And here's my HomePageComponent.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/components/HomePageComponent.scss';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

function HomePageComponent() {
  
  return <div>
    <Navbar> //Error Underline occurs here
    </Navbar>
    
    </div>;
}

export default HomePageComponent;
```

Comment: try <Navbar /> instead of <Navbar></Navbar>

Comment: Can you please do the simple like this `<Navbar />`.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that helped me out, too!